# How do i update the sorted column back into the datagridview and also changing its respective items

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, desktop-application

[Image of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjqPw.jpg)

So there are 4 columns ID,ItemName,ItemCategory and PriceAmount
What i want to do is sort the price amount by clicking the dropdown menu and i took out the price amount added it in an arrray and then sorted it using bubble sort but i am having a hard time finding out how do i update the datagridview as per the price amount and changing its respective columns too any help?
This is what i did

```
        int[] price = new int[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            price[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);

            for (int j = 0; j < price.Length; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(price[j]);
            }
        }



        int temp;

        for (int j = 0; j <= price.Length - 2; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= price.Length - 2; i++)
            {
                if (price[i] > price[i + 1])
                {
                    temp = price[i + 1];
                    price[i + 1] = price[i];
                    price[i] = temp;
                }
            }

        }

        foreach(int sortedArray in price)
        {
            Console.Write(sortedArray + " ");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

here is the code of the browse button

```
   private void browseBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        dialog.Filter = "Files(*.txt, *.csv)|*.txt;*.csv|All Files (*.*) |*.*";

        DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pathTextBox.Text = dialog.FileName;

        }

        if(pathTextBox.Text.Length>0)
        {
            importBtn.Enabled = true;
        }

    }
```

then it grabs the location of the .csv file and then adds in the textbox 
and then the insert button imports it

```
      private void importBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string value = pathTextBox.Text;
        importCSVDataFile(value);
        pathTextBox.Text = "";

    }
```

Code of importCSVDataFile

```
    private void importCSVDataFile(string filepath)
    {
        try
        {
            TextFieldParser csvreader = new TextFieldParser(filepath);

            csvreader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });

            csvreader.ReadFields();
            //int row_count = 0;
            while (!csvreader.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] fielddata = csvreader.ReadFields();

                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

                for (int i = 0; i < fielddata.Length; i++)
                {

                    dataGridView1.Rows[row_count].Cells[i].Value = fielddata[i];
                }
                row_count++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Import CSV File", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

I was performing a insert and update work with this

```
     private void insertBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string id = idTextBox.Text;
        string itemName = itemNameTextBox.Text;
        string itemCategory = categoryTextBox.Text;
        string itemPrice = priceTextBox.Text;

        if (this.status)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[this.row].Cells[0].Value = id;
            dataGridView1.Rows[this.row].Cells[1].Value = itemName;
            dataGridView1.Rows[this.row].Cells[2].Value = itemCategory;
            dataGridView1.Rows[this.row].Cells[3].Value = itemPrice;
            this.insertBtn.Text = "Save";
            dataGridView1.Rows[this.row].Selected = true;

            MessageBox.Show("Existing Record Updated");
        }
        else
        {
            int count = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
            dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value = id;
            dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[1].Value = itemName;
            dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[2].Value = itemCategory;
            dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[3].Value = itemPrice;
            dataGridView1.Rows[count].Selected = true;

            MessageBox.Show("New Record Saved!!");
            row_count++;


        }
        itemNameTextBox.Text = "";
        categoryTextBox.Text = "";
        priceTextBox.Text = "";
        this.status = false;
        this.row = 0;

    }
```

Sort Algorithm of Bubble Sort for itemName

```
    private void sortByItem()
    {
        int rows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < rows; j++)
            {
                string val1 = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[j - 1].Cells[0].Value);
                string val2 = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value);
                if (string.Compare(val1, val2) > 0)
                {
                    for (int a = 0; a < this.dataGridView1.Columns.Count; a++)
                    {
                        object temp = this.dataGridView1[a, j - 1].Value;

                        this.dataGridView1[a, j - 1].Value = this.dataGridView1[a, j].Value;
                        this.dataGridView1[a, j].Value = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I can suggest you the solution to this issue. But can you share the code of insert button click? I need to first understand how are you loading items into the gridview. Based on that I can provide you the answer which is easily understandable by you.

Comment: Please add the code to the original question. Code in comments is not readable at all. Are you loading data from the text file and binding it to DataGridView?

Comment: What is the code of `importCSVDataFile` method?

Comment: updated those codes in the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are binding data in the gridview is not right. That way you can not achieve functionality of sorting GridView.

What you need is a class which represents the data which are loading in the gridview.

Let say you have a product class as following.

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Now you have data of multiple products in the file so you need to create a list of products and initialize it in the form as following.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<Product> products;
    public Form1()
    {
        products = new List<Product>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Now method `importCSVDataFile` needs to be changed as following to load data from the file and populate the list and bind it to the grid view.

```
private void importCSVDataFile(string filepath)
    {
        try
        {
            TextFieldParser csvreader = new TextFieldParser(filepath);

            csvreader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });

            csvreader.ReadFields();
            while (!csvreader.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] fielddata = csvreader.ReadFields();

                var product = new Product();
                product.ID = Convert.ToInt32(fielddata[0]);
                product.Name = fielddata[1];
                product.Category = fielddata[2];
                product.Price = Convert.ToDouble(fielddata[3]);

                products.Add(product);
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = products;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Import CSV File", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Once you have data displayed in the grid, you need to change sorting code as following.

Let say you have `combobox1` which has column names listed to sort the gridview. So code of combobox1's `SelectedIndexChanged` event will be as following.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            var selectedColumnName = comboBox1.SelectedItem as string;

            switch (selectedColumnName)
            {
                case "ID":
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = products.OrderBy(product => product.ID).ToList();
                    break;
                case "Name":
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = products.OrderBy(product => product.Name).ToList();
                    break;
                case "Category":
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = products.OrderBy(product => product.Category).ToList();
                    break;
                case "Price":
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = products.OrderBy(product => product.Price).ToList();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

To add new products to the gridview you need to create new instance of Product and set its properties and then add it to the list and bind the list to the gridview again.

```
public void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var id = Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text);

    var objProduct = products.FirstOrDefault(product => product.ID == id);

    if (objProduct == null)
    {
        objProduct = new Product();
        objProduct.ID = id;
        objProduct.Name = txtName.Text;
        objProduct.Category = txtCategory.Text;
        objProduct.Price = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrice.Text);
        products.Add(objProduct);
    }
    else
    {
        objProduct.Name = txtName.Text;
        objProduct.Category = txtCategory.Text;
        objProduct.Price = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrice.Text);
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = products;
}
```

I hope this would help you resolve your issue.

Comment: Yeah thanks for that. I had done thing but in a different way before by making the class and making that class a binding source in the gridview and had problems changing the contents of it thanks a lot :)

Comment: Bro i did this it is working fine but i have 4 textboxes  which are ID ItemName ItemCategory and Price too from which i can add the data into the same grid view but now since we are adding the headers using fielddata index how can this be achieved? i mean adding the data into the same gridview

Comment: Can you share the code which sets the header using fieldData ?

Comment: yeah i updated it what i was doing was i had already added the column names in the gridview and then added the value in certain indexes as per the code above

Comment: So what issue you are facing? You don't know how to create new product from the textboxes and add it to the grid view?

Comment: Since i followed your way what happened is when i load up the form the datagridview is empty right i cant insert any data because there is nothing in the gridview like here : https://ibb.co/nL0nGb
and then when i do the import thing then this happens i cant insert the data
https://ibb.co/hNichG

Comment: Does the file have data? Are you loading the data from file to datagridview using method `importCSVDataFile` which I shared? Can you share the code of insertbutton click event too?

Comment: yeah the file have  data which is a .csv file and yeah i tried doing it as per your way

Comment: There is some thing wrong in your code. Data should be loaded from the file. Are you getting any error? Updated my answer with the InsertButton  Click Code

Comment: the data is loaded from the file in the gridview1 right but i also want to insert data manually into the datagridview1 through textboxes and i cant add data into the gridview1 using the textboxes now

Comment: so bro i did the sorting too using bubble sort algorithm. It was a necessary thing for my project to use any sorting algorithms i have updated it in the question :D :)